# How to add styles to a appended div done through Javascript in Css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

this is my **html** file

```
                      <div id="addingMembers">

                      </div>

                       <div class="selectMember">
                            <div class="selectTitle" (click)="addMember()">
                                <p class="selectMemTitle">Add a member</p>
                                <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="add icon">add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

this is my **Javascript** File:

```
  addMember(){
    const x = document.getElementById('addingMembers');   
    x.innerHTML+ = 
      `<div id="members">
      Hey I'm added
        </div> 
      `;
}
```

Here, I want to style my **members** div using CSS File, but the styles are not applying on it:

```
#addingMembers #members{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ::ng-deep pseudo-class to disables view-encapsulation. Or move your styles to global styles.

```
::ng-deep #addingMembers #members{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the control you are adding. Check below sample.

```js
function tes() {
            let change = document.getElementById("addingMembers");

            change.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="randomCls"/>';
        }
```

```css
 .randomCls{
            background-color:red;
        }
```

```html
<div id="addingMembers">
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="btn1" onclick="tes()" value="Check" />
```